# Deploying Django @ Heroku - Windows Libraries

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm using some python libraries on my Windows localhost (Django) server and I'd like to host my application online. My app is based on reading Excel files and providing this data on the screen.

```
import win32com.client as win32

import pythoncom
```

I suppose this are WindowsOS libraries only and I couldn't deploy @ Heroku, for being a LinuxOS server.

Am I correct? If so, are there other good free Windows servers?

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly are you using win32com.client?

Comment: My Excel files are password protected and the only way I figure out to remove this password was using this win32com.client module! My issue is: probably the Heroku server will not be able to run for being LinuxOS